# mvn install looks for tools.jar nested too deep within my java directory

Tags: java, maven, ant, maven-2, pom.xml

On ubuntu 11.10, with maven2, here's the error code:

Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:

> /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/../lib/tools.jar

Not sure why it's adding the ".." in the path?

My tools.jar is at /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/lib/tools.jar

I have done:
sudo apt-get install sun-java6*
sudo update-alternatives --config java , and chosen sun-java-6

uncommented the deb-src /etc/apt/sources.list

/home/raymond/.bashrc

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26
export JAVA_HOME
```

~/.profile

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26
export JAVA_HOME
```

/usr/lib/mvn

```
exec "$JAVACMD" \
  $MAVEN_OPTS \
  -classpath "${M2_HOME}"/boot/classworlds.jar \
  "-Dclassworlds.conf=${M2_HOME}/bin/m2.conf" \
  "-Dmaven.home=${M2_HOME}"  \
  "-Djava.home=${JAVA_HOME}" \
  ${CLASSWORLDS_LAUNCHER} $QUOTED_ARGS
```

pom.xml, I have this in my builds, plugins

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

java -version

```
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

javac -version

> javac 1.6.0_26

mvn -version

```
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (rdebian-6)
Java version: 1.6.0_26
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26
Default locale: en_CA, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux" version: "3.0.0-14-generic-pae" arch: "i386" Family: "unix"
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `mvn -X clean package` (in a pastebin)?

Comment: What's the actual issue? The extra `".."` wouldn't make a difference, it's still the `lib` directory of the Java install.

Comment: @DaveNewton Well it didn't let me compile because it can't find tools.jar

Comment: AH I FOUND the issue. It seems I needed to remove this line:
  "-Djava.home=${JAVA_HOME}" \
from /usr/lib/mvn that I posted in the question. I had added that line following a suggestion from googling. I guess setting the extra java_home had some conflicts.

Comment: @poleapple You sure you have a JDK there, or just a JRE? `JAVA_HOME` must point to a JDK.

Comment: I think for ubuntu, it's easier to just install all sun-java6 packages. I only installed -jdk earlier and ran into all sorts of problems trying to get mvn install to work. I think it started to work since I installed everything, I just had a bogus fix in there that prevented it from installing.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yep, definitely have the JDK. I checked the folders, and java -version checks out.

Comment: `java -version` isn't what I'm asking, and your answer confirms the suspicion.

Comment: If you have found the issue, and it has resolved, could you please add it as a answer and check mark on it please? It WIll help both, those who are facing same issue, and those who are trying to answer this Q :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I needed to remove this line: "-Djava.home=${JAVA_HOME}" \ from /usr/lib/mvn that I posted in the question. I had added that line following a suggestion from googling. I guess setting the extra java_home had some conflicts.

I think for ubuntu, it's easier to just install all sun-java6 packages. I only installed -jdk earlier and ran into all sorts of problems trying to get mvn install to work. I think it started to work since I installed everything, I just had a bogus fix in there that prevented it from installing.

Answer (score 1):

If you use eclipse copy tools.jar to [eclipse_folder]/jre
It effected for me...